# Ploting two barplots side by side

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Despite my best effort I having been able to find a satisfying answer and I'm therefore asking how to solve my issue. Please don't be to hard if I've been missing and already posted answer.

I'd like to compare two sets of values, plotted as bars, one being stacked and the other not.

Here is my code so far

```
seqdf = pd.read_csv("%s/%s" % (folder, seqfile), header=None, sep=" ")
pardf = pd.read_csv("%s/%s" % (folder, parfile), header=None, sep=" ")

seqdf2 = pd.DataFrame(seqdf.mean().values, columns=['sequencial']).T
pardf2 = pd.DataFrame(pardf.mean().values, columns=['parallel']).T

plt.figure(1)
colors = plt.cm.GnBu(np.linspace(.3, 1, 16))

plt.subplot(1,2,1)
seqdf2.plot.bar(color=colors, ax=plt.gca(), align='center', stacked=True)

plt.subplot(1,2,2)
pardf2.plot.bar(color=colors, ax=plt.gca())

plt.show()
```

and it gives me:
[image]

However I'd like to have both datasets on the same graph, with le first one (sequential) being as wide as one of the bars of the second one.

how can I achieve that ?

Comment: I think, you should provide your data in order for the community to be understandable (at least sample data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very fancy solution but you can do it as follows:

```
data = pd.concat([seqdf2, pardf2])
sp = plt.subplot(111)

data.mul([1, 0], axis=0).plot.bar(color=colors,
                                  ax=sp,
                                  align='center',
                                  stacked=True)

data.mul([0, 1], axis=0).plot.bar(color=colors,
                                  ax=sp,
                                  legend=False)
```

Comment: Perfect, I just had to add a small width=.05 to the first plot to achieve what I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution. I provide two solutions since I didn't quite clearly understand your problem:

```
new_df = pd.concat([seqdf2, pardf2])
```

**Option 1**

```
new_df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, colors = colors)
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

**Option 2**

```
new_df = new_df.unstack().unstack()
new_df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, colors = colors)
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

Comment: I don't want pardf2 to be stacked

Comment: If this is the case, you can simply type `stacked=False`

Comment: I still want seqdf2 to be stacked